# What's the HTML character entity for the # sign?

Tags: html, character, entity, html-entities, character-entities

What's the HTML character entity for the # sign?  I've looked around for "pound" (which keeps returning the currency), and "hash" and "number", but what I try doesn't seem to turn into the right character.

Comment: You should have searched for "octothorpe"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need it? # isn't a reserved character in HTML... If you need to escape it in a URL (to avoid starting a fragment), then using the HTML escape won't do you much good.

Comment: ...have you tried not using a character entity? If you view the source for this page no entity is being used to make the # characters.

Comment: i believe stack overflow uses utf-8. what i've inherited doesn't, so that's why.

Comment: @Shog9, Markdown interprets `#` as "headers", so we need to do `&#35;` , See the source code of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8333376/632951

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can search it on the individual character at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm). Enter `#` as search string and the 1st hit will lead you to [U+0023](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0023/index.htm). Scroll a bit down to the 2nd table, **Encodings**, you'll see under each the following entries:

```
HTML Entity (decimal)  &#35;
HTML Entity (hex)      &#x23;
```

Comment: A simple [ascii chart](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=ascii+chart&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=le3rVOmIDcfguQS7uIG4AQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%3Bs1dBG-qo3cDEJM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.asciitable.com%252Findex%252Fasciifull.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpdf.masdillah.com%252Fascii%252Fascii-symbols.html%3B715%3B488) will work just fine.

Comment: As indicated in another answer, there has been an update allowing to use `&num;` also.

Comment: thx for your answer. would you be able to elaborate a little more: what is the difference between using ` &#35;` vs `&#x23;`?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: one is written in decimal notation other is written in hex notation.

Comment: What's the meaning of # in the URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_formation#Protostar?

Comment: @user610620: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Now, how is it that # URI fragments for moving down to a lower section of a page is also used for # URI fragments that let people toggle through different columns of a table? Are both usages dependent on HTML or Javacript code? and how do their code differ

Comment: @user610620: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

Answer (score 25):

For `#` we have `&num;`.

Bear in mind, though, it is a new entity (IE9 can't recognize it, for instance). For wide support, you'll have to resort, as said by others, the numerical references `&#35;` and, in hex, `&#x23`.

If you need to find out others, there are some [very useful tools](http://amp-what.com/#q=#) around.

Answer (score 17):

The "#" -- like most Unicode characters -- has no particular name assigned to it in the W3 list of
"Character entity references"
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
.
So in HTML it is either represented by itself as "#" or a numeric character entity "&#x23;" or "&#35;" (without quotes), as described in
"HTML Document Representation"
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html
.

Alas, all three of these are useless for escaping it in a URL.
To transmit a "#" character to the web server in a URL, you want to use "URL encoding" aka "percent encoding" as described in RFC 3986, and replace each "#" with a "%23" (without quotes).

Comment: percent encoding is especially important when (sigh) your query sting includes an octothorpe, e.g.: `http://example.com?search=term#37` where `term#37` is your query string.

Answer (score 9):

There is no HTML character entity for the `#` character, as the character has no special meaning in HTML.

You have to use a character code entity like `&#35;` if you wish to HTML encode it for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

```
&#35; or &#x23;
```

http://www.asciitable.com/ has information. Wikipedia also has pages for most unicode characters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Answer (score 4):

The numerical reference is `&#35;`.

Answer (score 4):

You can display **"#"** in some ways as shown below:

```
&num; or &#35; or &#x23;
```

In addtion, you can display **"♯"** which is different from **"#"** in some ways as shown below:

```
&#x266F; or &#9839; or &sharp;
```

Answer (score 2):

We've got some wild answers here and actually we might have to cut hairs to determine if it qualifies as an HTML Entity, but what I believe you're looking for is the **named anchor**.

This allows references to different sections within an HTML document via hyperlink and specifically uses the octothorp (hash symbol, number symbol, pound symbol)

*exampleDomain.com/exampleSilo/examplePage.html#2ndBase*

Would be an example of how it's used.

Comment: Oh nevermind.  Answering a different question.

Comment: Funnily enough, you answered what I was wondering about, so +1

Answer (score -1):

# is the best option because it is the only one that doesn't include the # (hash) in it. Supported by old browsers or not, it is the best practice going forward.

(What is the point of encoding something using the same symbol you are encoding?)

Comment: Various reason could exist. One which I've experienced is to avoid markdown triggering a number list when the hashtag is used as the first character on a line.