# Update the row that has the current highest (maximum) value of one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query, which is wrong. I want to update the field "prevmonth" in the *wins* table, but only for the record that has the maximum value for the field "month_wins".

```
UPDATE wins
SET prevmonth_top=1
WHERE month_wins = (SELECT MAX(month_wins) FROM wins)
```

Error message:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wins' for update in FROM clause

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
UPDATE wins
SET prevmonth_top=1
ORDER BY month_wins DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or something like this:

```
UPDATE IGNORE giveaways
SET winner = 1
WHERE month_wins = (select maxID from (SELECT MAX(ID) maxID FROM giveaways) as t)
```

It is the ***same as*** *[You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333454/491243)*.

Comment: FWIW: The first solution is nice and short, but be very careful not to omit "Limit 1" at the end!

Answer (score 5):

Run the following query. It may help:

```
UPDATE wins
SET prevmonth_top=1 WHERE month_wins =
(
    SELECT month_wins FROM (SELECT MAX(month_wins) FROM wins) AS month_wins
)
```

Comment: much more simple and clear! great dude!

Comment: Minor nit: the use of `month_wins` in so many places makes this answer less clear than it could be.  I'd change the nested selects to something like `(SELECT maxWin FROM (SELECT MAX(month_wins) maxWin FROM wins) AS t)`.  This clarifies that `maxWin` is the max value, not another reference to the field `month_wins`, and that `t` is an arbitrary temp name.