# MYSQL clause not working: UPDATE WHERE MAX

Tags: php, mysql, max, where-clause

I have this piece of MySQL code that is driving me mad:

```
UPDATE Sells SET number = '$number' 
    WHERE id_student = '$id_student' AND id_book = '$id_book' 
    AND Hour = (SELECT MAX(Hour) FROM Sells WHERE id_student = '$id_student')
```

It doesn't blow up but it doesn't do what it is supposed to do either. If I take out the last part (the Hour clause) it works as it should, but when I add it as in the code above, it just does nothing (as if there where no Hours in the table, which is false). Hour type is INT.

Any ideas on how could I get the last clause working? Somehow it must be bad-written, but I can't see where.

Comment: See that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242466/update-row-with-max-value-of-field

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the filter on `id_book` in the subquery, as without it the `MAX(Hour)` returned by the subquery may be that of a record that has been filtered in the outer query:

```sql
UPDATE Sells
SET    number = '$number' 
WHERE  id_student = '$id_student'
   AND id_book = '$id_book' 
   AND Hour = (
         SELECT MAX(Hour)
         FROM   Sells
         WHERE  id_student = '$id_student'
            AND id_book = '$id_book'
       )
```

Note also that you appear to be quoting numeric literals as strings, which leads to unnecessary type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It will only update if the record both matches the book id *and* the latest hour for that student. If *one* of those preconditions is false, no row will match.

You may need to add the book condition to the subselect as well.

Comment: With the complete php code (which I haven't included), this case is not possible.
However, I found the solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause
Thanks!