# Inserting other column data into new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with columns id, begin, end, route.  Is there a way to select the max or previous rows end column value and insert it as the new row's begin value?

```
ID  Begin  End   Route
1     1    10     SW
2    10    21     NE
3    21    55     S
```

What I am trying to do is this...

```
INSERT INTO log ('id', 'begin', 'end', 'route') 
VALUES (DEFAULT, MAX('End"), 'xxx', 'xxx')
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: There is a way.  But without knowing the layout of your data, it is really hard to say more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `MAX` function to select the maximum value.

```
SELECT MAX(*column name*) AS *alias* FROM *table name*;
```

sgeddes and Slowcoder have provided answers for the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Given your edits, something like this should work using `max` with `insert into select`:

```
INSERT INTO log (`begin`, `end`, `route`) 
SELECT MAX(`End`), 'xxx', 'xxx'
FROM log
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc80/1)

Please also notice the use of backticks vs single quotes.  Use the backticks to delimit fields.

Comment: I get the following error.  "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @the1Texan -- this query doesn't use any derived tables (subqueries).  That error generally means you to alias your subquery.  What's your query?

Comment: INSERT INTO `log`(`ID`, `begin`, `end`, `route`) VALUES (DEFAULT,(SELECT maxend FROM (SELECT MAX(`end`) FROM `log`),'5000.1','SW')

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
INSERT INTO log (`id`, `begin`, `end`, `route`) VALUES (DEFAULT, (SELECT MAX(end) from log), 'xxx', "xxx');
```

Comment: This isn't valid sql syntax -- just because the OP writes it, doesn't mean we should copy it!

Comment: Why isn't it valid? Just curious.

Comment: @aphextwix -- before the edits, single quotes instead of backticks -- after the edits, double quote still needs to be removed --> `"xxx'` won't work either.  Getting closer though...

Comment: @sgeddes - Oh but the actual syntax of using a sub-query for the `SELECT` is fine though?

Comment: @aphextwix -- well, that too won't work either without tricking mysql with a subquery.  Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0b00b/1

Comment: @sgeddes is right.  The select query won't work here without a different table alias.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333376/you-cant-specify-target-table-table-name-for-update-in-from-clause