# Umbraco MySQL upgrade issue "can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"

Tags: mysql, umbraco7

## Update

It looks like the issue is due to the following MySQL statement:

`UPDATE cmsTemplate SET master = NULL WHERE 'master' IS NOT NULL AND 'master' NOT IN (SELECT nodeId FROM (SELECT * FROM cmsTemplate a) b)`

**Any ideas on how to make the above query compatible with MySQL?**

## Original Issue

We are having the following error when trying to upgrade our Umbraco installation (Server Core 2012 R2 / MySQL Database):

> 2016-12-07 15:49:25,532 [P5184/D5/T42] ERROR
>   Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Installation
>   step DatabaseUpgrade failed.
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallException: The database failed to upgrade.
>
> ERROR: The database configuration failed with the following message:
>   An error occurred running a schema migration but the changes could not
>   be rolled back.
>
> Error: You can't specify target table 'cmsTemplate' for update in FROM
>   clause. In some cases, it may be required that the database be
>   restored to it's original state before running this upgrade process
>   again.
>
> Please check log file for additional information (can be found in
>   '/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt') at
>   Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseUpgradeStep.Execute(Object
>   model) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
>   parameters) at
>   Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.ExecuteStep(InstallSetupStep
>   step, JToken instruction)

Any ideas how to resolve?

Many thanks,

Steve

Comment: Have also posted to the Umbraco Community Forum:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/81739-issue-upgrading-umbraco-from-724-to-latest-version

Comment: Nobody have any idea how to make the above query MySQL friendly??