# How to add the result of a query into a column

Tags: java, mysql, unix

I have the following query which returns a column of values:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
  from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
  CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 
  AS SIGNED)
) FROM IEX_Tick;
```

How can I copy this column to an existing column in the same table?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a subquery would do:

```sql
UPDATE IEX_Tick SET SomeColumn = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
       from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
       CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 AS SIGNED)
   ) FROM IEX_Tick;
)
```

---

**Edit:**

*<sup>(in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030095/how-to-add-the-result-of-a-query-into-a-column/48030125#comment83110663_48030125))</sup>*

After doing some research, I found that, even though the suggested solution above is valid `SQL`, it's not a supported way of updating a table in `MySQL`.

Information I gathered from various related posts here on Stack Overflow (such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333376/mysql-1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-giveaways-for-update-in-from-clau) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)) suggests that `MySQL` restricts these types of `UPDATE` queries:

> ... because your update could be cyclical… what if updating that record causes something to happen which made the WHERE condition FALSE? You know that isn’t the case, but the engine doesn’t. There also could be opposing locks on the table in the operation.

Therefore, a viable alternative that helps avoid this arbitrary restriction set by `MySQL` is to use another subquery, this time in your `FROM` clause, as shown below:

```sql
UPDATE IEX_Tick SET SomeColumn = (
   SELECT CONCAT(
       from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000, '%Y-%d-%m %h:%i:%s.'),
       CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM from_unixtime(lastSaleTime/1000))/1000 AS SIGNED)
   ) FROM (
       SELECT * FROM IEX_Tick AS SomeName
   );
)
```

**Note:** I would personally avoid using the `SELECT * FROM IEX_Tick`, especially if `IEX_Tick` has many columns. I good way to optimise the subquery would be to use only the column(s) needed.

Comment: I tried that but got the error "You can't specify target table 'IEX_Tick' for update in From clause. I've been searching and this seems to be a mysql thing

Comment: You are right @ajasif. Check out my edit. I did some research and found a solution that should be working for you 