# Why can't MySQL update a table and select from the same table in a subquery

Tags: mysql

At the bottom of the MySQL v5.6 [documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) for the UPDATE command it says:

> You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

For example, this will fail:

```
UPDATE actor
SET last_name = 'foo'
WHERE actor_id IN (
    SELECT actor_id 
    FROM actor 
    WHERE last_name = 'bar');
```

Note: Please assume the column `last_name` is not a part of an index.

Why is this not allowed and is there a stable workaround for it?

P.S. - Thanks for the workaround! Can you please also explain why the example above is not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple trick:

```
UPDATE actor
SET last_name = 'foo'
WHERE last_name = 'bar'
```

Whatever you are doing is same as the above query.

**Explanation:** You can't just update something you are selecting.

If you want to go with your flow still then give an alias to sub-query by using temporary table,

```
UPDATE actor a1
SET a1.last_name = 'foo'
WHERE a1.actor_id IN (
    SELECT a2.actor_id 
    FROM actor a2
    WHERE a2.last_name = 'bar');
```

OR

```
UPDATE actor a1 SET a1.last_name='foo' 
WHERE a1.actor_id IN (SELECT a2.actor_id 
                    from (SELECT * FROM actor) a2 
                    WHERE a2.last_name = 'bar');
```

In other words in MySQL, you can’t modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part. This behavior is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

And on stackoverflow [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333376/mysql-1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-giveaways-for-update-in-from-clau) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).

> **Note**:*This is because your update could be cyclical… what if updating that record causes something to happen which made the
>   WHERE condition FALSE? You know that isn’t the case, but the engine
>   doesn’t. There also could be opposing locks on the table in the
>   operation.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain why I can't update something that I'm selecting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to avoid the subquery?

```
UPDATE actor
SET last_name = 'foo'
WHERE last_name = 'bar';
```

Comment: Too much where ).

Comment: This works and I'm surprised - shouldn't using a non-PK column in the WHERE clause trigger MySQL's Safe Update Mode to block this command?

Comment: Okay so the reason your SQL statement works is that in my DB (Sakila sample DB) there is an index (key) on the last_name column. So this is not a stable workaround I'm sorry to say.