# MySQL - Why is Safe Update Mode blocking this UPDATE command?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have an `actor` table that looks like this:

```
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1        | Jack       | Nicholson | 2019-06-02 00:00:00 |
```

Column `actor_id` is a primary key with auto increment.

When I try to update the table like so:

```
UPDATE actor
SET last_name = 'foo'
WHERE last_update > '2019-06-02 00:00:00';
```

I get blocked by MySQL's safe update mode with this error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Indeed column `last_update` is not a KEY column, so based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719602/33404) I've come up with the following workaround:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids AS (SELECT actor_id FROM actor WHERE last_update > '2019-06-02 00:00:00');

UPDATE actor
SET last_name = 'foo'
WHERE actor_id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM ids);
```

But again I'm blocked with a 1175 error.

Why is safe update mode blocking me here? Can I work around it without disabling safe update mode?

Comment: Just disable the safe mode if you know the statement is the right thing to do? If you want it in general, you can reenabale it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. That's very pragmatic of you but doesn't quite answer my question :)

Comment: [why](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) do they think that they need to 'protect' you from doing false (or slow) sql-statements?

Comment: @Luuk, because it's very common for beginners to make this sort of mistake, and recovering from the mistake might take a lot of work.

Comment: @Bill, but some 'experts' hate this kind of things... LOL (I am not calling meself an expert here!)

Comment: I would also comment that a _true_ expert doesn't hate this sort of thing, because they understand that it helps to avoid mistakes. **"An expert is someone who knows some of the worst mistakes that can be made in his subject, and how to avoid them." — Werner Heisenberg**

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this error by making the column a KEY column. In other words, create an index (aka key) on the column.

```
mysql> set sql_safe_updates=ON;

mysql> UPDATE actor SET last_name = 'foo' WHERE last_update > '2019-06-02 00:00:00';
ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column

mysql> alter table actor add key (last_update);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE actor SET last_name = 'foo' WHERE last_update > '2019-06-02 00:00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The point of the error is to prevent you from unintentionally locking every row in the table when you have a condition on a non-indexed column.

The way locking works, it locks all rows that the query *examines* to test the condition, not just all rows that satisfy the condition. If you run a query with a condition that tests an unindexed query, it has to examine every row in the table, which probably locks way more than you intended it to lock.

Comment: Swell explanation, thank you! Though the workaround is a bit heavy handed for the task wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: You might find that it's helpful for other reasons to have an index on that column. Also, you can turn off [sql_safe_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates) just in your session, without changing the global setting for the option.